# Font too bold in IE10

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML table headers which are made bold by using CSS "font-weight:bold". This looks fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE10 in IE8 mode, but when I visit the page in IE10 in IE10 mode the text is far too bold.

How to fix this?

```
*{
    font-family:        Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:          12px;
}
.widetableheader{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: Where is your CSS? You need to post it

Comment: It wouldn't be an asp.net site would it?

Comment: OS: W7, W8? Which font? Which size? ANY details, seriously?

Comment: @TimBJames Not using ASP. It's PHP on IIS.

Comment: See CSS attached now, sorry. The class is linked to the <tr> of the table so that all <th> and <td>'s in it are made bold.

Comment: add body { font-size: 100%; }

Comment: @TamilSelvan Has no effect...

Comment: Using Windows 8 with IE10 for testing. When I put IE10 in IE8 mode or lower, the "boldness" matches Chrome/ff.

Comment: As it isn't asp.net but on IIS, this fix might work. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx

Comment: I've created a sample code here which exactly reproduces the issue you described: http://jsfiddle.net/fTaGL/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by using:

```
*{
    font-family:        Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:          12px;
    font-weight:        normal;
}
```

So by adding font-weight at the "root" of the CSS sheet.
Thanks all for the possibilities!

Answer (score 5):

To target IE10 Specifically you will need to use javascript, as they've dropped the conditional comments. (thank you stereoscott for pointing this out) Here's a quick way to do this using jquery:

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 10) {
  $("html").addClass("ie10");
}
```

If IE9 or lower, I would recommend doing Conditional Comments.

To do this, first setup a style sheet specific to IE10, you'll probably run into other things that look weird in IE as IE is the best browser at breaking your code and making things look bad.

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie10.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Now within that style sheet just specify the font-weight, as it will only apply to IE 10:

```
.widetableheader{
  font-weight:500;
}
```

Manipulate that number in the font-weight till you get it just fine in IE.

Good luck, and let me know if you have any questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a numeric value.

Further reading:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/font-weight

Comment: Tried this, but setting it to value 700 (bold) has the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a 'correct' solution, but using jquery you can just set a new set of styles:

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 10.0) {
    $("html").addClass("ie10");
}
```

In CSS:

```
.ie10 .widetableheader{
    font-weight:500;
}
```

There may be more elegant solutions.